# faking $wp_query->post_founds

Tags: calendar

i'm trying to make a calendar without plugin

Most part of the job is to display multiple times a post (ie : a event like a concert can have 3 dates )
I've firstly try to create a post by date, so duplicating post for differents dates, but it ending with tons of posts, and managing them with a front-end page for user as one unic event (create /modify / delete) is time-consuming and donesn't seems a well practice.

So as I can't make a regular loop to display a same (post) multiples times in a wp_query, I've seen a good idea : having a taxonomy call "event_date" and adding each dates of the post in.

The concept of the code is :

- Find all no empty taxonomy terms (get_term)
- make a foreach on them to ... (foreach)
- ... loop each dates to find post related with (wp_query)
  and you've got a list like

```
• 2023-05-18
- name of an event A
- name of an event B

• 2023-05-22
- name of an event C

• 2023-05-22
- name of an event A
- name of an event B

• 2023-05-23
- name of an event C

• 2023-05-24
- name of an event c
- name of an event B

• 2023-05-30
- name of an event C

• 2023-06-15
- name of an event C
```

It looks working like a charm, until I'm try the pagination. Making the pagination cause me 404 link on certains last pagination-links. I explained the fact that I can have more dates than event pages. For example the main loop is waiting for 5 posts (i 've got 5 posts for now in my event CPT) and the posts_per_page on WP dashboard is set to 2. So WP will need 5/2 = 2,5 -> 3 pages to display them.

But if I've got 7 dates in my taxonomy, I'm waiting for 7/2 = 3,5 -> 4 pages of pagination.

And that's why my "4" pagination link fall into a 404 page.

THIS is approximately understood.
So my first thought was `pre_get_post` but my main loop is a `foreach`, so no impact on the main query.

So i've try to brutaly change in `pre_get_post` something like :

```
$wp_query->max_num_pages = 4;
$wp_query->post_founds = 7;
```

... but there no effect (naive!)

**SO! my BIG question :**

- how can I fake all this ?
- making wordppress believe to aa fake max_num_pages and post_count / post_count values

**#UPDATE**
This code is basically in the index.php but not in the main loop.
This code works, but as it's not in the loop I need the wp_query updated in order to expects the same number of page type: "/page/x"

```
        $custom_cats = 'events_dates';

        $big = 999999999;

        $page = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

        $per_page = get_option( 'posts_per_page' );

        $offset = ( $page - 1 ) * $per_page;

        $term_args = array(
            'number'        => $per_page,
            'offset'        => $offset,
            'hide_empty'    => true,
        );

        $terms = get_terms( $custom_cats, $term_args );

        if ($terms) {

            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                $term_link = get_term_link( $term );

                echo '<li>';

                wp_reset_query();

                $args = array('post_type' => 'events', 
                    'tax_query' => array(
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => $custom_cats,
                            'field' => 'slug',
                            'terms' => $term->slug,
                        ),
                    ),
                );

                $loop = new WP_Query($args);

                if($loop->have_posts()) {

                    echo '<h3><a href="'.$term_link.'">'.$term->name . ' ( ' . $term->count . ' )</a></h3>';

                    echo "<ul>";

                    while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();

                        echo "<li>";

                        echo '<a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a><br/>';

                        echo "</li>";

                    endwhile;

                    echo "</ul>";

                }

                echo '</li>';
            }   

        }

        bootstrap_pagination( $wp_query  );
```

Thank's all
Nico.

Comment: I'm currently here : interesting function "wp_add_cache"
https://barn2.com/blog/create-fake-wordpress-post-fly/

Comment: I'm not sure if you're actually doing it correctly, but you can use the [`found_posts` filter hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/found_posts/) to modify the `found_posts` value.

Comment: So what the correct approch please ?
I've followed : https://weusewp.com/tutorial/paginate-taxonomy-terms/

Comment: Sorry, I don't really know about the proper approach for what you're trying to do. I was only responding to the way you were attempting to modify the `found_posts` value. However, if you can provide more details like where are you doing this (what page is it), what template you are using, the template code, sample posts, sample output, etc., then maybe I can help you further.

Comment: Ok I misundestood, the code is updated in the inital post. Thank's.

Comment: I think your approach is good, in that using a taxonomy is much better than using post meta for the event dates. However, you should not fake the `found_posts` value, because what would the main loop display on page 4? Page 3 (i.e. the posts on the last page) of the main query? Or an empty main loop? So you might better off use a custom pagination *query var* like `evcal_page` (and not `paged`), in which case you wouldn't need to fake anything. Or use JS+AJAX to load the next/previous pages of your calendar.

Comment: Also, there's no need to call `wp_reset_query()` and instead, call `wp_reset_postdata()` after your custom loop ends ( e.g. `endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();` ).

Comment: What do you think about another ranking :
-> creating another cpt called "cpt_dates"
-> create a new post call 20230518 with a custom field filled with concerned ids for this date.

Comment: Whether you use a custom taxonomy to store the event dates, or a CPT and then custom field to store the dates, you'd actually still end up with the same pagination issue, if you're creating a secondary/custom `WP_Query` loop (which needs a pagination) on an archive/non-singular pages like the home page (which uses the index template). But taxonomy queries are more *performant* than meta queries, so think carefully whether you want to use a custom field which then would need a meta query.